Create "private" js export
Concider a js module that contains 3 files : A.js, B.js and C.js.
In A.js I do export the variable a because I need it in B.js and in C.js.
I want to provide to users that use my module an easy access to elements exported from B.js and from C.js, but user should not use the const a from A.js.
So, a pseudo code for A.js would be something like this :
const a = something;

export a withRestrictions ('B.js', 'C.js');

I never seen something like this, but maybe there is a trick that I ignore. Something equivalent to editing __init__.py when working with python.

Look into the things you can do with the "exports" directive in package.json. It's not clear what exactly you need, but with "exports" you have a lot of control over how something using your package can "see" the resources you want to expose/hide.

Now, if you're working with browser JavaScript, things are different, because import is handled by browser logic, not Node. Plus it depends on what bundler you use and the options it provides.

I see. Editing package.json seems indeed to be a neet solution.


In A.js I do export the variable a because I need it in B.js and in C.js.

A way to keep a from A.js 'private' is to export a function from B/C.js, within which you can use a closure for a. In that case you don't have to export a.
// A.js
import _b from B.js;
import _c from C.js;

const a = 42;
const b = _b(a);
const c = _c(a);


// B.js
export default BFactory;

function BFactory(a) { ... }

// C.js
export default CFactory;

function CFactory(a) { ... }

